# can I select #id > #id with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

can I select #id > #id with jQuery?

I've got this structure

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div id="slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2">
    <div id="slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to select, using jquery, only the #slide_body inside #slide1?

Or is the only solution to append the id to each body div like

```
<div id="slide2">
    <div id="slide_2_slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use unique IDs in one document

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique
>   in a document.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

In your example you may use class "slide_body"

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div class="slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you can select it with `#slide1 .slide_body` or `$("#slide1").find('.slide_body')`

Answer (score 14):

The answer to the first question:

> can I select #id > #id with jQuery?

You can infact do that exact syntax `$('#slide1 > #slidebody')`. The `>` character means direct descendant and is called the child selector (http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). If the element may not be a direct descendant but nested inside something else you would omit the `>` and end up with `$('#slide1 #slidebody')`.

As for the HTML snippet most are correct in mentioning that it is bad to have the same id on different elements and is considered an invalid document.

http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/LzFAr/

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
$('#slide1 > #slide_body')
```

Comment: I don't find this works. But instead, this does: `$('#slide1 #slide_body')`. Is it due to a different JQuery version? I'm using v1.11.4

Answer (score 3):

Your markup is invalid. You cannot have two elements with the same ID. For this reason, the answer is no. Use classes instead.

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div class="slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2">
    <div class="slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>

$('#slide2>.slide_body');
```

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me, and I was looking for a solution, the truth that none of the ones published here worked for me and I found something that worked for me ($('#container').find('#child')):

```js
var div = $('#container').find('#child4').html();
alert(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Container:
  <div id="child1">Child Div 1</div>
  <div id="child2">Child Div 2</div>
  <div id="child3">Child Div 3</div>
  <div id="child4">Child Div 4</div>
  <div id="child5">Child Div 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique on the page. Use classes instead:

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div class="slide_body">
        some content
    </div>
</div>
```

And then `#slide1 .slide_body` as the selector.

Comment: @flem Thanks for spotting that, have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The id of an HTML element should be unique.  Turn slide body into a class.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div class="slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2">
    <div class="slide_body">
    some content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Selector**

```
$("#slide1 .slide_body")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select like that, however it is entirely redundant as `id` attributes should be unique within the page. With that in mind, your current code is invalid. You should use a `class` where you need to group identifiers:

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div class="slide_body">
        some content
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2">
    <div class="slide_body">
        some content
    </div>
</div>
```

You would then use:

```
var $slideContent = $('#slide1 .slide_body');
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all, it's not very good decision to have non-unique ids. Despite of this you can pass context in jQuery function:

`$("#slide_body", "#slide1")`

Comment: -1 for *"not very good decision"*. It's invalid, therefore not a decision to be made but rather a bug to be corrected. The workaround **IS** a *"bad decision"*.

Comment: @flem agree that this is a bad decision. But do you know ALL circumstances OP working with? What if this markup generated by some server code and OP can't affect this?

Comment: In such a scenario, OP should be looking for a solution to the real issue, in this case having non-unique identifiers. If server code generates it that way, fix the server code. If a third party component generates it that way, get on to the vendor of change the component. There's no argument here. Never use non-unique IDs. It's invalid.